# Android Ads Missing XML attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, admob, ads

I know this question might have been asked before, but i am unable to fix my issue using those answers.

My problem is when i add my AdView to my layout using eclipse, i get the message: Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing.

This is my current activity XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="mycodehidden">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

ALso there is no ad shown when i run this.

Answer (score 0):

You're combining both the old and new admob apis which is wrong.

Using admob via the google play services library, change the ad xml namespace:

**from :**
 `xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

**to :**
   `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

**Then in the manifest's application tag:**

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Don't forget the permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```